# Tracking clicks vs installs with GA Google Play Campaign Attribution like in AppsFlyer

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk, install-referrer

In [AppsFlyer](http://www.appsflyer.com/), when a user clicks on a referral link that redirects to my app in the Play Store, AppsFlyer immediately records a 'click' from that campaign. The user is shown the page for my app. If they then decide to install my app, a `BroadcastReceiver` of type `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` is launched. AppsFlyer's SDK implements this `BroadcastReceiver` by sending the campaign's source and medium that caused that install to their servers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600087/google-play-campaign-tracking-without-google-analytics-implementation-android) to get and idea of how the `BroadcastReceiver` is implemented.

I can then easily see via the AppsFlyer dashboard how well a campaign is performing by measuring clicks vs installs per campaign and calculating clickthrough rate.

[image: AppsFlyer dashboard]

Can I track clicks vs installs without AppsFlyer using Google Play URL Builder and [Google Analytics SDK - Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) or some other 3rd party tool?
I see how GA tracks installs by implementing `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` and sending the install to the GA Dashboard, but can I also measure how many users are seeing the Google Play download page for my app and then deciding to not install it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to work without a 3rd party if you're just tracking Google campaigns for an Android app. However, you most likely want to track across channels (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, iAd, ad-networks, email campaigns, etc.) in which case it would be necessary to set up with a dedicated attribution partner like AppsFlyer. This will also enable you to take advantage of critical tools for ad-operations, such as retargeting and re-engagement campaigns, smartlinking/deeplinking, etc.

Regarding your second question, you should be able to see the number of page views for your app in Google Play as a result of campaigns and search.

Comment: I just need to generate links with campaign info in URL and keep track of traffic. Where can I find page views per campaign in Google Developer Console? Which panel? Or do I need to integrate GA?

Comment: In this instance, your best bet is AppsFlyer (I'm assuming you're already set up with them)... I'm not entirely sure regarding GA and page views...

Comment: @hallaplay835 How are you tracking install counts using Appsflyer?